# How to find hostnames of devices on local network in addition to model, MAC, and IP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, network-discovery

I am able to use NMAP and arp-scan to find local IPs, MAC addresses, and device Models. However this is unable to find any device names (not models like Apple). Using Nmap with DNS reverse lookup with -R does not report any additional information, with sample output such as

```
Nmap scan report for 10.66.66.183
MAC Address: 28:FF:3C:96:14:30 (Apple)
```

However the output I'm looking for is similar to

```
Name: (John's Iphone pro) 
IP: 10.66.66.183
MAC Address: 28:FF:3C:96:14:30 
Brand: (Apple)
```

which is easily obtainable on any Android apps I tried such as [Network Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myprog.netscan&hl=en_US&gl=US).

I tried every method I could find to reproduce these results, such as nbtscan, nmap detection with -A, -sP -sn, arp-scan, and none of them were able to find a single hostname. What could the apps be doing differently and how can I perform a similar scan?

Comment: I use something called AngryIPScanner for this purpose, with command line utilities you could do a arp -a and then tracert on one of those IP addresses, you could even create a script to automatically output the hostnames and IPs into a text file.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: No, I am on linux

Comment: Are you asking for how to massage the output of `nmap` to your format?

Comment: I am asking how to find the name of the device similar to the app, which nmap is unable to do